# Can JSON values be numbers?

Tags: javascript, json

Can JSON values (not keys) be numbers, or do they HAVE to be strings only? So the following is valid.

```
{"number":"6"}
```

But is the following also valid?

```
{"number":6}
```

Comment: yep that's fine. And if you parse it in JavaScript it will automatically treat it as a number and not a string. Therefore, your two examples are actually supplying different data, due to the change of type, which is important to note. You can easily test this yourself using any online JSON validator.

Comment: Let's forget about javascript for the moment. Is `{"number":6}` valid json?

Comment: JSON / Javascript objects are interchangable - you write a JS object in exactly the same way as JSON (they are the same thing, that's what "**J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation" means, and where it originated from), so saying "forget about javascript" is a bit meaningless :-). And it wouldn't just be JS that parsed it differently, any other deserialiser parsing it into another language should also (hopefully) make the distinction correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json values can be

- a string
- a number
- an object (JSON object)
- an array
- a boolean
- null

See - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp

Answer (score 2):

It is valid JSON syntax. But beware that different programming languages will parse JSON differently..

https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, 6 is the number six. "6" is a string containing the digit 6. So the answer to the question "Can json numbers be quoted?" is basically "no," because if you put them in quotes, they're not numbers anymore.

The only thing that needs to be between quotes is the property name (*number*).